# How to replace only tokens, an no substrings?

Tags: java, regex, replace

I'm looking for a way to replace only full tokens, and not substrings of tokens, like:

```
String test = "a | ab & c | a";
```

Now I want to replace "a" with anything else, but this should only replace "a", and not "ab".

```
test.replace("a", "1"); //would result: "1 | 1b & c | 1"
```

How can I only replace "full words"?

By the way, the replacement of the tokens between the special characters "|" or "&" come from:

```
\\s*[|&][|&\\s]*
```

This is my regex to separate them. Maybe I could use this regex again to replace??

Comment: In this case you can use `test.replace("a ", "1 ");`

Comment: What separates tokens? Whitespace? Punctuation?

Comment: updated above: my separators are one or more of the alphabet: "|&"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a regex with a word boundary (`\b`) which will only replace "isolated" `a`s:

```
test.replaceAll("\\ba\\b", "1");
```

Example:

```
String test = "a | ab & c | a";
System.out.println(test.replaceAll("\\ba\\b", "1"));
```

prints `1 | ab & c | 1`.

Answer (score 0):

How about `test.replaceFirst("a", "1");`  ?

Comment: I want to replace all occurences of single "a", updated my example to make it more clear.